# perl : function calls

Tags: perl, function

The below  script is used to ssh into a router,read information form the file abc.txt and execute the commands. The script works as expected.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

print "\n[INFO] script Execution Started\n";


my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
  host     => "ip addr",
  password => ' user ',
  user     => 'pwd',
  raw_pty  => 1,
);

my $login_output = $ssh->login();


$ssh->exec("enter command 1");
$ssh->exec("enter command 2");
open my $pr, '<', 'abc.txt';
while (my $config = <$pr>) {
chomp $config;
my $conf =  $ssh->exec("$config");
print("$conf");

}
```

Now I converted a  part of the above code to a function.This is what i tried.
So what i'm trying to do is make a function call to open a file. `mysub($ssh,"abc.txt");`
So that i can reuse this code in my program to open multiple config files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

print "\n[INFO] script Execution Started\n";


my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
  host     => "ip addr",
  password => 'user',
  user     => 'pwd',
  raw_pty  => 1,
);


sub mysub {

my ($ssh,$filename) = @_;
$ssh->exec("command 1");
$ssh->exec("command 2");
open my $pr, '<', $filename;
while (my $config = <$pr>)
{
chomp $config;
my $conf =  $ssh->exec("$config");
print("$conf");

}

mysub($ssh,"abc.txt");

}
```

The function call part doesn't work its not throwing any error. Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 5):

If you use proper indentation, your error becomes evident:

```
sub mysub {
    my ($ssh,$filename) = @_;
    $ssh->exec("command 1");
    $ssh->exec("command 2");
    open my $pr, '<', $filename;
    while (my $config = <$pr>)
    {
        chomp $config;
        my $conf =  $ssh->exec("$config");
        print("$conf");

    }
    mysub($ssh,"abc.txt");   # this should be outside
}
```

You have to put the function call outside of the subroutine.